# Issue with implementing logic to filter top 10 data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to list similar jobs based on the current job the user is viewing.

**Current Job Location:**

**Local Zone:** Vancouver Downtown

**City:** Vancouver

**State:** British Columbia

Now, I want to show similar jobs based on the following criteria :

Step 1: Filter jobs based on "Vancouver Downtown", "Vancouver" and "British Columbia" and return the 10 jobs order by ""Vancouver Downtown" localzone

Step 2:  If we don't find 10 jobs in step 1 then we find jobs in "Vancouver" and "British Columbia" and return the 10 jobs order by "Vancouver".

Step 3:  If we don't find 10 jobs in step 2 then we find jobs in "British Columbia" and return the top 10 jobs order by just "British Columbia".

So search order to find similar jobs starts from lowest level that is "Local Zone", then if not there, we move to "City" and vice versa.

In the final result, I want to list down the jobs starting from the lowest level "Local Zone" and then we move to "City" and then "State".

**Table :**

```
Jobs:
JobId   Title      LocationId       Salary


Location:
LocationId    CountryId      StateId    CityId      LocalZoneId
```

**Query :**

```
DECLARE 
    @currentJobId INT = 101,
    @currentJobLocalZoneId INT = 201,
    @currentJobCityId INT = 301,
    @currentStateId INT = 401
SELECT TOP 10
        j.JobId,
        j.Title,
        j.Salary
        l.StateId,
        l.CityId, 
        l.LocalZoneId
        FROM Jobs j
        LEFT JOIN Location l ON l.LocationId = j.LocationId
    
        WHERE 
            j.JobId != @currentJobId
            AND (@currentJobLocalZoneId IS NULL OR l.LocalZoneId = @currentJobLocalZoneId)
            AND (@currentJobCityId IS NULL OR l.CityId = @currentJobCityId)
            AND (@currentStateId IS NULL OR l.StateId = @currentStateId)
 
        ORDER BY 
            -- not sure how do i order results that starts from lowest level "Local Zone" and then we move to "City" and then "State"
```

But here in above query, I am confused with how do I implement bottom up approach of first starting from "Localzone" and if we don't find 10 jobs then we move to "City" and then "State".

Can someone please help or guide me to implement this part?

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to create an expression that returns an integer representing the "closeness" of the result. For example, in your case, you could use:

```
CASE WHEN l.LocalZoneId = @currentJobLocalZoneId THEN 1
     WHEN l.CityId = @currentJobCityId THEN 2
     WHEN l.StateId = @currentStateId THEN 3
     ELSE 4
END
```

...and then you `ORDER BY` this expression.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but how do I use this expression to then return the top 10 jobs based on my 3 criteria? Sorry, I am a little confused

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow: `ORDER BY CASE WHEN ... END` should do the trick. It makes sure that your query returns results with matching local zone first, then results with matching city, etc. Or did I misunderstand your requirement?

Comment: This case logic is in "Where" part or in "Select" part? Is it possible if you can show me how do I use your logic in my query? I will really appreciate it :)

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow: Neither. You keep your query exactly as you have it in your question and just add the code part from my answer right behind "ORDER BY".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the parameters are part of a hierarchy, i.e. the local zone is contained in the city which is contained in the state, you need to perform a query that combines the results of increasingly broad matches:

```
select top 10 JobId, Title, Salary, StateId, CityId, LocalZoneId
  from (
    -- Local Zone.
    select J.JobId, J.Title, J.Salary, L.StateId, L.CityId, L.LocalZoneId,
      1 as OrderRank -- These results come first.
      from Jobs as J left outer join
        Location as L on L.LocationId = J.LocationId
      where J.JobId != @currentJobId and -- Never include the current job.
        L.LocalZoneId = @currentJobLocalZoneId
    union all
    -- City.
    select J.JobId, J.Title, J.Salary, L.StateId, L.CityId, L.LocalZoneId,
      2 -- Second choice results.
      from Jobs as J left outer join
        Location as L on L.LocationId = J.LocationId
      where J.JobId != @currentJobId and -- Never include the current job.
        L.CityId = @currentJobCityId
    union all
    -- State.
    select J.JobId, J.Title, J.Salary, L.StateId, L.CityId, L.LocalZoneId,
      3 -- Third choice results.
      from Jobs as J left outer join
        Location as L on L.LocationId = J.LocationId
      where J.JobId != @currentJobId and -- Never include the current job.
        L.StateId = @currentStateId
    ) as FilteredJobs
    order by OrderRank;
```

Note that the filter values need to be set properly, e.g. if you want to filter by City then *both* `@currentJobCityId` *and* `@currentStateId` need to be set correctly to allow the fallback from City to State if the City doesn't have 10 appropriate jobs available.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but can you tell me the difference between the query in the first answer and the query in your answer? Sorry, just for my learning purpose and knowledge :)

Comment: The `where` clause in your query requires that each filter value is either `null` or matches jobs. Using `and` to combine them means that you only get results that match _all_ of the specified criteria. By splitting them apart to search for local, city and state matches and then combining them with `union all` my answer implements your Steps 1, 2 and 3 and adds the correct handling of `top 10` and `order by` to get the 10 "closest" jobs. Heinzi's answer orders the values correctly, but it doesn't fix your basic query to handle the three Steps.